# aborting debian jammy not supported

Tags: 22.04

Trying to install Tpot on ubuntu desktop 22.04

via code below

```
git clone https://github.com/telekom-security/tpotce
cd tpotce/iso/installer/
cp tpot.conf.dist tpot.conf
./install.sh --type=auto --conf=tpot.conf
```

The output says `Aborting. Debian jammy is not supported`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the script is only configured to run in Debian Stable and Debian Testing, and not Ubuntu. However, it may be compatible with Ubuntu, given most of the packages are the same.

To bypass this check, open the `install.sh` file in a text editor, and in [line 364](https://github.com/telekom-security/tpotce/blob/master/iso/installer/install.sh#L364), replace

```
mySUPPORT="FALSE" --> mySUPPORT="TRUE"
```